# Phpstorm constantly freezes up and is left hanging/unresponsive

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

I’m running Ubuntu 18.04, when I open phpstorm it often takes a very long time to index my files, while it does this it effectively maxes out my CPU (i7). If I try and open another project it’ll quite often fail at this point (if it hadn’t when I initially opened storm) and go completely unresponsive. The only way to close it when this happens is by restarting, killing the process doesn’t close it somehow?
Another thing to note is it also sometimes freezes when I try and open the phpstorm inbuilt terminal
Any ideas?

Edit: 32GB ram

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @gronostaj sorry I should’ve included this, 32GB